# Using Feedburner with both RSS and Atom feeds

Tags: analytics, rss, feeds

I might be misunderstanding the concept completely, but here's the question: when I try to add a blog's feeds (the blog is hosted at Blogspot, so it provides both Atom and RSS) to FeedBurner, it suggests to choose *one* of the feed formats. Is it possible to track subscribers of both the both feed formats? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FeedBurner takes your source feed and populates RSS *and* ATOM feeds on its own site.

<s>Try adding `?format=atom` to the end of an existing RSS feed hosted at FeedBurner for an example.</s>

It looks like the result is an aggregate XML document which uses a variety of formats:

```
<rss xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/" 
 xmlns:wfw="http://wellformedweb.org/CommentAPI/"
 xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
 xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
 xmlns:sy="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/syndication/" 
 xmlns:slash="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/slash/"
 xmlns:feedburner="http://rssnamespace.org/feedburner/ext/1.0" version="2.0">
```